# Firebase admin sdk verifyIdToken verifies any token from any firebase projects

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin, google-signin

I have created two projects from https://console.firebase.google.com/ in one email account and another project from another email account. And configured to use android and google authentication login. This works perfectly when I copied the `google-services.json` in to the android project. I've done this for all 3 firebase projects and the backend verifies all 3 tokens successfully using method `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken)`
I downloaded the googleservicekey.json to backend from one of the projects.

My question is why `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken)` verifies all the tokens not just the particular project token ? what am I missing here ?

All the jwts generated by the projects has the same "kid": ""
(these jwts are returned by the firebase googlelogin in android)

Comment: i feel this is a big security hole

Comment: Explanation below. If you still think there's a security risk in being able to verify an ID token, I recommend clarifying what the risk is.

Comment: Firebase uses the same keys to sign all ID tokens. The key itself is cycled out periodically. Regardless, usually you can't verify tokens from different projects at the same backend, because they have different `iss` claims. Can you check the `iss` claim on your tokens?

Comment: Sounds like the start of an answer @HiranyaJayathilaka :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the comments but it looks like the problem was to do with the build cache. even though Ive changed the google-services.json file running the project was still using the old json file, so I had to clean and build and it worked. thanks